# React Navigation transitionConfig Color

Tags: react-navigation

I see there is an option for transitionConfig to enter values such as the animation style or the duration. I was wondering if there was a way to change the color of the background during the transition (the semi-transparent background that appears during the transition)? For example, I have fairly dark screens and during the transition the background kind of flashes white.
Is this  either configurable directly, or is it maybe a property of the parent navigator?
Thanks

I see during the transition process the area between the focussed screen and the edge of the screen goes from white with an opacity of 1 to transparent. Is it possible to maybe begin from another color such as black?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same.

Comment: No unfortunately :/ I thought maybe it was the colour of an underlying screen but it always seems to go white to transparent regardless.

Comment: I used `opacity: 1` to fix this for me, although the animation does not look that great anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
```

in your StackNavigatorConfig

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding this to my StackNavigator:

```
cardStyle: {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  opacity: 1,
},
```

Now the transition is completely transparent. I tried using only `opacity: 1` as suggested but it didn't work. I'm using `"react-navigation": "^1.5.11"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are were a **TabBarNavigator** component then you can have a look at [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig) part of the documentation to fix color problems during transitions.

If you combine *swipeEnabled*, *animationEnabled* and *lazy* properties you will get a better result in transitions. Otherwise, a gray/transparent color will be used during screens' transitions.

```
    const tabNavigatorConfig: TabNavigatorConfig = {
        ...
        swipeEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: false,
        lazy: false,
        ...
    };
```